# How to run ink! e2e tests in GitHub CI

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node, contracts

The directory structure for my project is something like this

```
ink
 - contract
runtime
node
and so on
```

I want to run the contract `ink/contract` e2e tests in GitHub CI using my own node instead of the `substrate-contracts-node`. I didn't find any existing solutions for this. Can anybody provide any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this workflow as an example: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/.github/workflows/examples.yml to setup the environment.

If you want to use your own node, you can supply a path to the executable using `CONTRACTS_NODE` env var.

e.g.

```
CONTRACTS_NODE=my_node cargo test -F e2e-tests
```